# Shared Shortcuts/Icons

Tags: inno-setup

I have several inno setups with shared files. With the 'Sharedfile' flag a can make sure that the they only get uninstalled if they're no longer used.

However this is not working for shortcuts or icons as they are called in inno pointing to those files. shortcuts are always getting removed even if the target file is not getting uninstalled.

So is there something i'm missing? a flag for shortcuts?

or do you have some starting point on how to prevent this in code?

Thanks a lot

Comment: There is no such flag. I would use the `uninsneveruninstall` flag for the `[Icons]` entry and write a code that will check if the shortcut target file exists and only if it does not, delete the shortcut. This I would do as a post uninstall action.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response. I give it a try. 
Shouldn't this be a default, by the way?

Comment: Sadly, icons are not reference counted.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks alot TLama this seems to be working:

I prevent my shard icons from being uninstalled with the 'uninsneveruninstall' flag.
Then in pascal, check if the file still exists if not manually delete the shortcut or folder:

```
procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
    begin
        if CurUninstallStep = usPostUninstall then
            begin
                if (not(FileExists(ExpandConstant('{app}\executable1.exe')))) then DelTree(ExpandConstant('{group}\myfolder'), True, True, True);
                if (not(FileExists(ExpandConstant('{app}\executable2.exe')))) then DeleteFile(ExpandConstant('{group}\myShortcut.lnk');
            end;
    end;
```

Personally i think that inno setup should do this by default, checking if the installed shortcuts target is reference counted and use this value for the shortcut.

But anyhow thank you all very much and have a nice day.

Comment: In a more generic way it is possible to resolve the shortcut path by using `IShellLink` interface.